# How to use By.XPATH to find last element?

Tags: pydev

On  Claim screen I want to always click on last Submit button.

Currently shows 4 Submit butyons ( can be more ) with xpaths of:

Death Select1 = //*[@id="container"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[8]/a

Death Select2 = //*[@id="container"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[8]/a

Death Select3 = //*[@id="container"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[8]/a

Death Select4 = //*

@id="container"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[8]/a

Tried this with no success:
id="container"]/table/tbody/tr[last()/td[8]/a]').click()

See above
self.browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container"]/table/tbody/tr[last()/td[8]/a]').click()